# Parse Crash Analytics Unsymbolicated After Uploading DSYM File

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, crash-reports

I have an app that is already in the App Store and I got a crash report that is a unsymbolicated. I tried to upload the .dSYM file using the following procedure, but Parse is still showing me the unsymbolicated crash report. I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong.

Let's say the app is named MyApp

1. In Xcode, I open the Organizer using Window > Organizer
2. I locate my latest MyApp Archive, and I right click on it then Show in Finder
3. I right click on MyApp.xcarchive file and choose Show Package Contents
4. I navigate into the dSYMs folder and get the directory (I also see here MyApp.app.dSYM file)

In Terminal, I upload the dSYM file using this:

1. I cd into my parse cloud folder which is in my project folder
2. Then I type the following:

`parse symbols MyApp --path="/Users/EmadToukan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-08-15/MyApp 2015-08-15, 7.28 PM.xcarchive/dSYMs/MyApp.app.dSYM"`

When I hit enter, I get the following:

```
Uploading iOS symbol files...
Uploaded symbol files.
```

When I refresh my Parse Analytics page, it still says that the crash report is unsymbolicated. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Did you contact Parse Support?

Comment: I posted this question and tagged @ParseIt on Twitter. Is there another way in which I can get in touch with them?

Comment: I think when you upload you need to upload the DWARF file, which is located a bit deeper in the archive at `parse symbols APP_NAME --path="<dSYM/xcarchive/DWARF path>"`. To get there right-click on the MyApp.app.DSYM file and again do show contents. That said, I did this and only one crash was symbolicated, others were left unsymbolicated, and I still had the "This stack trace is unsymbolicated" message at the top, regardless of whether it was symbolicated or not.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted this as a comment originally because I didn't think I was seeing correct results. Now I realize that I am.

So what you need to do is upload the file found in DWARF directory of your archive. This can be found at `dSYM/xarchive/DWARF/app_name`, where "app_name" will actually be the file you want to upload.

Once you do this, from what I can tell from Parse's docs, previous crashes that were unsymbolicated will **not** be symbolicated. Instead, a new crash will be generated with symbols. It's a bit confusing because the duplicate, unsym crashes remain there afterwards. You can find this information on Parse's website [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#crash-reporting-why-aren-39-t-my-crashes-symbolicated-)